# Remove GET parameter from url with php

Tags: php, sorting

I'm trying to build a sorting system for my posts on my blog.

When a user sort for ex: date, date and title the system sort the result on a new page by array of GET parameters.

Ex: www.domain.com/blog?date[]=thedate&date[]=thesnddate&title=sometitle

To control the sortings i display the form with radio inputs buttons to selecting the dates and title

When a visitor search the first time i display an info box with the current search filters.

So with the example above i would display:
Date: the date & thesnddate
Title: some title

Now what i need to know is how the best way is to remove one of the dates with PHP.

I tried outputting the information is seperate input buttons with both the same ID and with another ID but this either duplicate the information or keeps them the exact same. When taking one off the other would be assigned to the url.

Is there a way the replace the content of the url without remove all of the same?

Ex: 
preg replace the word date from the url. But this wouldn't work because then it removes all of the dates and i only want it to remove a single date.

Comment: This question comes across to me at least as very vague. Can you be more precise with exactly what you are looking for, what you have tried, why it didn't work and why you are mixing up URLs with PHP outputs ?

Comment: This is too unclear to really answer. However, you can access the URL parameters as array using `$_GET`; use that to take it apart and assemble it as necessary. If you need more concrete help, a concrete code sample and a problem description thereof would be helpful.

Comment: It is very hard to understand your question. Also, putting code on a separate line, in code tags is going to help get you more answers.

Comment: http://php.net/parse_url http://php.net/parse_str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a fiddle.](https://3v4l.org/BBQGt)

Works for PHP 5.3+

```
// Make array from query string
// If using the url from a string
$str = "www.domain.com/blog?date[]=thedate&date[]=thesnddate&title=sometitle";
parse_str(explode("?", $str)[1], $params);

// If using the query string from the current url...
//parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $params);

// Remoove one of the dates
unset($params['date'][0]);

// Re-create the url
$newDomain = "www.domain.com/blog?".http_build_query($params);

print_r($newDomain);
```

Comment: Really Nice! Excatly what i ment! How do do unset the variable equal to a specific value eg. from a $_get. So if the get value is thesnddate it will remove from string as if it was ['date'][1]?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you have a new question please ask a new question. If I helped please mark my answer. Good luck to you..

Answer (score 0):

Its not a PHP-solution but I think it would be possible to do it with the ".htaccess"-File in your root directory.
Once I had similar stuff to do and thats how I solved my problem

In your case: (www.domain.com/.htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blog$ www.domain.com/blog?date[]=thedate&date[]=thesnddate&title=sometitle
```

This would rename the entire URL, when it fits to the right URL, to the left one.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Im not 100% sure, but this could help.